# How to efficiently process the contents of a parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I'm trying to insert each `row` of a parquet file as a message in a redis stream. I'm relatively new to python so I've got an implementation working but it's quite slow.

The slow part isn't inserting in to Redis, it's actually looping through the data in the parquet file to access each row. Even if I remove the redis insert and replace it with a `print()` statement the loop is quite slow.

On my test file of 10k rows it takes 4-5 secs, and I need to be able to perform this operation on files with 1.6m rows...

Here's what I've got so far...

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from walrus import *
import pandas as pd

[...some redis setup removed here for brevity]

# Func to convert the PD series in to string then add to the redis stream
def add_to_stream(row):
  string_row = row.to_string()
  reader_stream.add({'message': string_row })

# Read the parquet file
df = pd.read_parquet('../data-small.parquet')

# Loops through the dataframe and inserts each row to the redis stream
# this is probably really inefficient, but just a POC
df.apply(add_to_stream, axis=1)
```

I have been searching for ways to bulk add parquet files but can't seem to find one. I'm sure looping through each row isn't the most efficient way of doing this, but I also need each row to be its own message in the redis stream.

Comment: did you look at LPUSH, RPUSH and pool of connections to redis?

Comment: The slow part here is looping through the parquet file rows, so I'm not sure they help

Comment: you say the slow part is "inserting to redis" that's what you say in the post. (insert == write not read)

Comment: but for a lot of row working on "per entry" basis is good maybe is panda supporting asyncio? insertion to a database can be time consuming if it is done synchronously

Comment: I wrote that the slow part isn't inserting in to redis

Comment: as I said before, when working on millions of entries it is good to go one by one. But if you think you have enough memory, you can completely load you parquet's datas into the RAM first and apply 'to_string' to all the entries  and at the end insert all thoses entries into redis with something like LPUSH.It will speed you script at the expanse of memory as I said.  Millions of entries can consumme many Gigabytes of RAM.

Comment: Ah, interesting approach - thanks for the tip.

Comment: note! take care of LPUSH! it only pushes many entries into a redis List! so you would need to create one befero pushing anything